# Git : Delete a branch and go back to the previous status

Tags: git, github

I was working in branch "tree" containing three files x.c, y.c and z.c (all are committed). I created a new branch "stack" (inside "tree"), added two files w.c, z.c. Then I remembered "stack" should have been created from "DataStructure". So I switched back to "tree" and deleted the branch "stack" (git -d branch stack).

But in "tree" x.c, y.c z.c && w.c, z.c are present. How will I get the previous status of tree branch (only x.c, y.c z.c files).

I tried:
git reset --hard sha_of_last_commit_in_tree , didn't work.

Comment: Did you change to the new branch "stack" before you commited the files ? or you only created the branch ? It seems that you committed to the "tree" branch

Answer (score 0):

After you did git reset --hard last_commit_in_tree what's git status of your files in repo? Are they all in index? Where do you see them?
I agree with @Saifu Khan it seems you forgot to switch to stack branch. Look at "git log tree" to understand what happend in this branch.